# How to inline Text widgets in flutter that are wrapped with another widgets

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list of strings and I want the Text widgets to be at the same line
I try this code :

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List str = [
      "This is text one,",
      "text two,",
      "looooong text three,",
      "text four,",
      "looooong text five,",
      "very very very long text six,",
      "text seven,",
    ];
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
      appBar: customAppBar(
        context,
        "",
      ),
      body: Text.rich(
        textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
        TextSpan(
          children: str.map((e) {
            
            return WidgetSpan(
                child: InkWell(
              onTap: () {},
              child: Text(
                "$e ",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
                textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
              ),
            ));
          }).toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

But if the whole sentence is larger that screen size it will be in another line like in the image :
[image]

and this is what I want the text to be : 
 [image]

I can achieve this using `TextSpan` widget:

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List str = [
      "This is text one,",
      "text two,",
      "looooong text three,",
      "text four,",
      "looooong text five,",
      "very very very long text six,",
      "text seven,",
    ];
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
      appBar: customAppBar(
        context,
        "",
      ),
      body: Text.rich(
        textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
        TextSpan(
          children: str.map((e) {
              return TextSpan(
              text: "$e ",
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ); 
            
          }).toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

But in this case I can't wrap the text with any widget.(I don't want to use only `on_tap` property to use the `recognizer` property in `TextSpan` widget)
I tried using `Wrap` widget but it didn't solve the problem :

```dart
Wrap(
        textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
        
        children: dummyList.map((e) {
          return InkWell(
            onTap: () {},
            child: Text(
              "$e ",
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
              textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
            ),
          );
        }).toList(),
      ),
```

Using row and expanded also didn't solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Try use `str.join(' ')`:

```
 List str = [
    "This is text one,",
    "text two,",
    "looooong text three,",
    "text four,",
    "looooong text five,",
    "very very very long text six,",
    "text seven,",
  ];
```

and widget:

```
Scaffold(
  body: Center(
    child: Text(str.join(' ')),
 ),
)
```

Comment: I don't want to join the list to one text, I want Text widget for each string in the list to wrap it with another widgets.